# Showing that a vector isn't in the span of a set

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have the vector

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
      1        \\[0.55ex]
      2        \\[0.55ex]
      3
\end{array}\right]$$

and I have to show that it is in the span of two other vectors

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
      1 & 2 & 5         \\[0.55ex]
      2 & 3 & 6        \\[0.55ex]
      3& 4 & 8
\end{array}\right]$$

Is then the other two matrices in an augmented matrix. I do row operation to get

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
      1 & 0 & 0         \\[0.55ex]
      0 & 1 & 0         \\[0.55ex]
      0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$

Which is inconsistent because 0 is not equal to 1. I then can claim that the matrix is not in the span. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: What are the two other vectors you span? If they are $(2\;3\;4)$ and $(5\;6\;8)$, you're getting the right conclusion for the (arguably) wrong reason.

Comment: Crap, why are my reasons wrong?

Comment: You want to solve $x(2\;3\;4)+y(5\;6\;8)=(1\;2\;3)$. Then the standard procedure would be to place the $(1\;2\;3)$ column to the _right_ of the vertical bar and the two spanning vectors to the _left_.

Comment: Oh I see that now, but would this change the result of the inconsistent matrix?

Comment: Not in this case, but there are similar problems where the row echelon form could end up being either $\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1 & 0 & \_ \\ 0 & 1 & \_ \\ 0 &0&0 \end{array}\right]$ or $\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1 & \_ & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 &0&0 \end{array}\right]$ depending on where in the original matrix you place the column you want to test.